# android onclick getting caught by wrong class

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my onClick is getting caught in the wrong class.

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter and inflating a custom row.

In my row.xml I have put onRowClick in the onClick method and in the code behind I have:

```
public void onRowClick(View v)
{ 

     //do something;

}
```

The flow of the app is:
Login => Show ListView

I call `finish()` in Login if successful  and then call intent to open the class with the ListView.

My problem is that the onClick gets caught in the Login class and not in the ListView class.

Code:

```
public class TabComeLeave extends Activity 
{
    private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null; 
    private ArrayList<Item> m_items = null;
    private ItemAdapter m_adapter;
    private Runnable viewItem;

    private ListView listViewItem;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_come_leave); 

        listViewItems = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewItems);
        listViewItems .setClickable(true);

        fillItemList();              
    }

    public void fillItemList()
    {  

        m_adapter = new ItemAdapter(SystemUtil.getInstance(), R.layout.list_row_come_leave, m_Items);               
        listViewItems.setAdapter(m_adapter);                      
    }
```

ItemAdapter.java:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> 
{
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> items) 
    {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) 
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)SystemUtil.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_come_leave, null);               
            }
            Item item = items.get(position);
            if (item!= null) 
            {
                    TextView itemName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);


                    if (itemName != null) 
                    {
                        itemName .setText(item.getitemFirstName());                            
                    }                    
            }           

            return v;
    }    
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: post your code. Hard to tell without seeing any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `onItemClickListener` instead of `onRowClick` when using a ListView, this problem would have no chance to occure then.

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: That did the trick!
But for it to work I had to extend ListActivity instead of normal Activity and the hooking up the adapter by using getListView().setAdapter(m_adapter);

Thanks a lot!